# Can't override AppCompat PopupMenu

Tags: android, xml

I am just trying to use an overriding style for the `PopupMenu`.

I am attaching it to my overall style like this

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/red</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/red</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:attr/colorBackground</item>
  <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
  <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
  <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>  
  <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
</style>
```

This is the style

```
<style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
  <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The parent can't be found. Which parent do I need here?

Comment: Please post entire styles.xml.

Comment: I just added the whole xml.

Comment: Did you try `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu`?